# How to add song to playlist during playback by using just_audio flutter

Tags: android, flutter

My app downloads audio files to device and has a audio player which plays that audio.
So I am trying to add song to my playlist while audio is playing. I am using flutter package  `just_audio: ^0.9.7` . I query all the songs from device from a specific folder and use these two function in init state

```
 Future<List<AudioSource>> _getList(List<SongModel> something) async {
  List<AudioSource> _list = [];
  something.forEach((element) {
    _list.add(
      AudioSource.uri(
        Uri.directory(element.data.toString()),
        tag: MediaItem(
          id: element.id.toString(),
          title: element.title.toString(),
        ),
      ),
    );
    print(element.data);
  });
  return _list;
}

Future<void> settingAudioPlayer() async {
  List<SongModel> something = [];
  something =
      await OnAudioQuery().querySongs(sortType: SongSortType.DATA_ADDED);
  something
      .removeWhere((element) => !element.data.contains('StrikleDustiness'));
  //print('${something[0].data}');
  var items = await _getList(something);
  await MainScreen.player.setAudioSource(
    ConcatenatingAudioSource(useLazyPreparation: true, children: items),
  );
}
```

by doing this I am able to play song whenever I restart the app. But I want to add song  to the playlist whenever I download  new song while playing  the existing song . I want the new download song to be my next queue.

Sorry for the bad english and also I am new to flutter.
Thanks..

EDIT: I figured it out. I just had to create a separate list containing all the video sources.